# Creating a list of all Regex Expressions

Tags: python, regex

Trying to create a list of all Regex expressions... Looking for anything with the format of 
`name='[xxxxx]'`, and anything with that format should be added to a list element. See below code.

```
fpath = open('Netezza_twb.txt', 'r')
lines = fpath.readlines()

temp_out_lines = [line for line in lines if '<column caption' in line]
new_var = [line for line in temp_out_lines if 'param-domain-type' not in line]

for x in range(len(out_lines)):
    test_v2 = str(new_var[x])
    new_var[x] = re.findall(r"name='\[(.*?)\]'", lambda m: m.group(1).lower(), test_v2)
```

I previously used re.sub() to lower all the elements in the txt file, but now I would like to gather all elements fitting the above regex format, into a list. `name='[xxxxx]'`

Note re.findall() might not be the best function, as I dont have much Regular expression coding experience. The regex expression however `r"name='\[(.*?)\]'"` Has proven to work previously, so I believe that the issue is not in the formatting of that.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please share all relevant code and data. See: [mcve].

Comment: @AMC, thanks for the response, but the Answer below solves the issue I was having. I will take into account the link you provided for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix syntax used by `re.sub` with that of `re.findall`.

Use

```
results = []
fpath = open('Netezza_twb.txt', 'r')
  for line in fpath:
    if '<column caption' in line and 'param-domain-type' not in line:
      results.extend(list(map(str.lower, re.findall(r"name='\[([^][]*)]'", line))))
```

**Notes**

- `for line in fpath:` - reads the file line by line
- `if '<column caption' in line and 'param-domain-type' not in line:` only processes a line that contains one string and not another
- `re.findall(r"name='\[([^][]*)]'", line)` extracts the matches captured in Group 1 (the contents between `name='[` and `]'`)
- `list(map(str.lower,...))` converts the matches to lower case
- `results.extend` adds the found matches to a list.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks so much for the quick response! @Wiktor Stribiżew